# Modal not remaining hidden using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following table setup to pop up with a modal window when you click on a row in the table. Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2et6qqux/6/). This is not working properly as modal actually isn't hidden. My HTML appears to be valid but I'm not sure about this line:

```
<td align="center" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
            <input class="ignoreBox" type="checkbox" name="ignore" value="one">
</td>
```

Can you have a form element inside a td element and are there any other suggestions to get the modal working?

EDIT:

Code for modal function:

```
$(function () {
$('#orderModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false,
}).on('show', function () {
    var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');
    $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'));
});
});
```

Comment: Where's the code for your modal function? E.g. `$('#orderModal').modal({`. Neither jQuery nor jQuery UI have a built-in `.modal()`

Comment: It's in the JS section of the Demo but I will edit my question to include the code here.

Comment: @j08691 it's from `bootstrap.js`

Comment: @Caludio Redi reminded me that modal was part of Bootstrap and I forgot to add it in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2et6qqux/12/)

Your javascript wasn't working so you needed to call the bootstrap files properly in the jsFiddle. I added a `tab-index` to your modal as a modification of the html. Even though that works. you might want to add a `modal-dialog` div and a `modal-content` div. These two will help with styling of the modal. See the difference in the code.

```
<div id="orderModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">   
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
     <h3>Detailed Comparison</h3>

</div>
<div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Method modal belongs to `Bootstrap` as you seems to know since you tagged your question properly. Problem here is that you're not including `Bootstrap` framework anywhere. Add reference and your code should work (with a few modifications on your modal HTML, more info [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

Comment: I added the Bootstrap which fixed the hiding of the modal but it still does not pop up when you click on the row.

Comment: Fix your modal html following `Bootstrap` example